# Creating a recursive method to remove specific objects from a 2D array

Tags: java, swing, recursion

I am making a game similar to tetris that uses squares and ellipses. I want to make a method that will remove similarly colored blocks when a circle of the same color is placed next to them. I want it to remove all the similarly colored blocks that are connected to these blocks as well. The proxy pieces are added to a 2D array of color shapes when they proxy piece hits the bottom of the board or another shape in the 2D array.

Edit: I updated me code that added William's floodfill algorithm. However I get a null pointer from his line:

```
if(_tiles[next.x][next.y].getColor().equals(colorToRemove))
```

here is my main JPanel where the 2D array is:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
public static final int COL_COUNT = 8;
private static final int VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT = 16;
public static final int ROW_COUNT = VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT;
public static final int TILE_SIZE = 30;

private boolean _pauseState;
private JLabel _pauseText;
private int _randomNum;

private javax.swing.Timer _timer; //  = new javax.swing.Timer(500, this); //board timer

//2D array of ColorShapes to record Color Shape placements
private ColorShape[][] _tiles; 

private ProxyPiece _proxyPiece;
private Piece _newPiece;

//Key Interactors for the up,left,and down arrow keys
private LeftListener _leftListener;
private RightListener _rightListener;
private DownListener _downListener;
private PauseListener _pauseListener;


public GamePanel()
{
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    _pauseState = false;
    _timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, this);

    _pauseText = new JLabel("PAUSED");
    _pauseText.setLocation(30,100);
    add(_pauseText);


    _leftListener = new LeftListener(this);
    _rightListener = new RightListener(this);
    _downListener = new DownListener(this);
    _pauseListener = new PauseListener(this);
    _tiles = new ColorShape[8][17];



    _proxyPiece = new ProxyPiece();
    _proxyPiece.setPiece(this.newPiece());

    for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
            _tiles[j][i] = null;
        }
    }

    //create a hidden bottom row of black rectangles to act as a boundary for the     pieces in the array
    for (int j=0; j<8;j++){
            _tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
     }
    _timer.start();
}

public void dropDown(){
    if(_tiles[_proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30][_proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30 + 1] == null){
    _proxyPiece.moveDown();
   }
   else if ((_tiles[_proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30][_proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30 + 1] != null) && (_tiles[3][0] == null)){
    //record the piece into array
        int _currentCol = _proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30;  
        int _currentRow = _proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30;



        _tiles[_currentCol][_currentRow - 1] = _proxyPiece.getFirstPiece();  
        _tiles[_currentCol][_currentRow] = _proxyPiece.getSecondPiece();
        repaint();

         purge();  



     //checks for a GameOver
     if(_tiles[3][0] != null){
       _timer.stop();
       System.out.println("Game Over");
        }


      _proxyPiece.setPiece(this.newPiece());
      repaint();
   }

 }

  // i = row , j = col
 public void purge(){
  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
        if(_tiles[j][i] != null){
           if(_tiles[j][i].getShapeType() == 2){ //checks if object is a circle
               //insert a recursive function that looks up,down,left,right for similar colors and sets spot to null
               removeLikeColorsFrom(_tiles,j,i);  
            }
             else continue;
        }
        else continue;
    }
}
repaint();
}

 //flood fill algorithm
 // x=col , y=row
 public void removeLikeColorsFrom(ColorShape[][] _tiles, int x, int y){
Color colorToRemove = _tiles[x][y].getColor();
Stack<Point> stack = new Stack<Point>();
stack.add(new Point(x,y));
while(!stack.empty()){
    Point next = stack.pop();
    //check if this shape is the proper color
    if(_tiles[next.x][next.y].getColor().equals(colorToRemove)){
        _tiles[next.x][next.y] = null;
        x = next.x;
        y = next.y;
        //now push all neighbors onto stack for processing
        if(x-1>-1 && _tiles[x-1][y] != null) 
            stack.push(new Point(x-1,y));
        if(x+1<_tiles.length) 
            stack.push(new Point(x+1,y));
        if(y+1<_tiles[0].length) 
            stack.push(new Point(x,y+1));
        if(y-1>-1) 
            stack.push(new Point(x,y-1));
    }
}
```

}

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
   if(_proxyPiece.getPiece() == null){
     _proxyPiece.setPiece(this.newPiece());
    }
   else {  
     dropDown();
     repaint();
    }

}

//factory method that produces a random shape
public Piece newPiece(){
    _randomNum = randomNumber(1,3);

    switch (_randomNum){
        case 1:
           return new Piece(new ColorEllipse(randomColor()), new ColorEllipse(randomColor())); //a new 2 Ellipse Piece w/ random colors
        case 2:
           return new Piece(new ColorRectangle(randomColor()), new ColorRectangle(randomColor())); 
        case 3:
           return new Piece(new ColorEllipse(randomColor()), new ColorRectangle(randomColor()));
        default:
           System.out.println("randomNumber failed");
    }

    //default return value to test if switch case failed
    return new Piece(new ColorRectangle(Color.RED), new ColorRectangle(Color.RED));
} 

public Color randomColor(){
    _randomNum = randomNumber(1,4);
    switch(_randomNum){
        case 1:
            return Color.GREEN;
        case 2:
            return Color.BLUE;
        case 3:
            return Color.RED;
        case 4:
            return Color.YELLOW;

    }
    //default return value to test if switch case failed
    return Color.RED;
}


public static int randomNumber(int low, int high){
    return low + (int)(Math.random()*(high-low+1));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (_pauseState == false){
    _pauseText.setVisible(false);
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // simplify the positioning of things.
    g.translate(0, 0);

    //Draws the board outline and fills it white
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 240, 480);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 240, 480);

    //Draws a dark gray grid 
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    for(int x = 0; x < COL_COUNT + 1; x++) {
         for(int y = 0; y < VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT+1; y++) {
             g.drawLine(0, y * TILE_SIZE, COL_COUNT * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE);
             g.drawLine(x * TILE_SIZE, 0, x * TILE_SIZE, VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT * TILE_SIZE);
         }
      }

    Graphics2D aBetterPen = (Graphics2D)g;    
    _proxyPiece.fill(aBetterPen);

    for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
            if(_tiles[j][i] != null)
             _tiles[j][i].fill(aBetterPen);
        }
    }
}
   else if (_pauseState == true){
       _pauseText.setVisible(true);
       super.paintComponent(g);
       // simplify the positioning of things.
       g.translate(0, 0);
       g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       g.drawRect(0, 0, 240, 480);
       g.fillRect(0, 0, 240, 480);

    }

}

private class LeftListener extends KeyInteractor{
    public LeftListener (JPanel aPanel){
        super(aPanel, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if( (_proxyPiece.getXLocation()>0) && (_tiles[_proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30 - 1][_proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30] == null) ){
        _proxyPiece.moveLeft();
        repaint();
      }
    }

 }
private class RightListener extends KeyInteractor{
    public RightListener (JPanel aPanel){
        super(aPanel, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if( ((_proxyPiece.getXLocation()<210)) && (_tiles[_proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30 + 1][_proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30] == null) ){
        _proxyPiece.moveRight();
        repaint();
      }
    }

 }
private class DownListener extends KeyInteractor{
    public DownListener (JPanel aPanel){
        super(aPanel, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Loop that will keep dropping the piece until it hits another piece or the bottom of the board
        while(_tiles[_proxyPiece.getXLocation()/30][_proxyPiece.getYLocation()/30 + 1] == null){
          dropDown();
        }
    }
}    


private class PauseListener extends KeyInteractor{
    public PauseListener (JPanel aPanel){
        super(aPanel, KeyEvent.VK_P);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (_pauseState == false){
            _timer.stop();
            _pauseState = true;
            repaint();

        }
        else if (_pauseState == true){
            _timer.start();
            _pauseState = false;
            repaint();
        }
    }

 } 

}
```

here is my ProxyPiece class:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class ProxyPiece
{
private Piece _currentPiece; // peer object
public ProxyPiece()
{
  super();
  _currentPiece = null;
}
public Piece getPiece(){
    return _currentPiece;
}
public ColorShape getFirstPiece(){
    return _currentPiece.getFirstShape();   
}
 public ColorShape getSecondPiece(){
    return _currentPiece.getSecondShape();   
}
    public void setPiece(Piece aPiece){
    _currentPiece = aPiece;
}
public void moveLeft(){
    _currentPiece.moveLeft();
}
public void moveRight(){
    _currentPiece.moveRight();
}
public void moveDown(){
    _currentPiece.moveDown();
}
public int getXLocation(){
    return _currentPiece.getXLocation();
}
public int getYLocation(){
    return _currentPiece.getYLocation();
}
public void rotate(){}

public void fill(Graphics2D aBetterPen){
    _currentPiece.fill(aBetterPen);
}
}
```

here is my Piece Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Piece
{
private final int X_START = 90;
private final int Y_START = 0;
private ColorShape _colorShape;
private ColorEllipse _colorEllipse1, _colorEllipse2;
private ColorRectangle _colorRectangle1, _colorRectangle2;
private int _type;

public Piece(ColorEllipse firstEllipse, ColorEllipse secondEllipse)
{
    _colorEllipse1 = firstEllipse;
    _colorEllipse2 = secondEllipse;
    _type = 1; //a Piece that has 2 Ellipses
    this.setLocation(X_START,Y_START);
}

public Piece(ColorRectangle firstRectangle, ColorRectangle secondRectangle)
{
    _colorRectangle1 = firstRectangle;
    _colorRectangle2 = secondRectangle;

    _type = 2; //a Piece that has 2 squares
    this.setLocation(X_START,Y_START);
}

public Piece(ColorEllipse firstEllipse, ColorRectangle secondRectangle)
{
    _colorEllipse1 = firstEllipse;
    _colorRectangle1 = secondRectangle;

    _type = 3; //a Piece that has 1 ellipse and 1 square
    this.setLocation(X_START,Y_START);
}

public void setLocation(int x, int y){
    if (_type == 1){
     _colorEllipse1.setLocation(x,y);
     _colorEllipse2.setLocation(x,y+30);
    }
    else if (_type == 2){
     _colorRectangle1.setLocation(x,y);
     _colorRectangle2.setLocation(x,y+30);
    }
    else if (_type == 3){
     _colorEllipse1.setLocation(x,y);
     _colorRectangle1.setLocation(x,y+30);
    }

}

//public void rotate(){
//    newX = centerOfRotationX - centerOfRotationY + oldYLocation; 
//    newY = centerOfRotationY - centerOfRotationX - oldXLocation;
//    
//    this.setLocation(newX, newY);
//}


public void moveLeft(){
    if (_type == 1){
       if((int)_colorEllipse1.getX() > 0){ 
       this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX()-30, (int)_colorEllipse1.getY());
      }
   }
   else if (_type == 2){
        if((int)_colorRectangle1.getX() > 0){ 
        this.setLocation((int)_colorRectangle1.getX()-30, (int)_colorRectangle1.getY());
      }
   }
   else if (_type == 3){
      if((int)_colorEllipse1.getX() > 0){ 
       this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX()-30, (int)_colorEllipse1.getY());
      }
   }
}
public void moveRight(){
   if (_type == 1){
     if((int)_colorEllipse1.getX() < 210){   
      this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX()+30, (int)_colorEllipse1.getY());
     }
   }
   else if (_type == 2){
     if((int)_colorRectangle1.getX() < 210){      
      this.setLocation((int)_colorRectangle1.getX()+30, (int)_colorRectangle1.getY());
     }
   }
   else if (_type == 3){
     if((int)_colorEllipse1.getX() < 210){        
     this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX()+30, (int)_colorEllipse1.getY());
    }
   }
}
public void moveDown(){
    if (_type == 1){
    this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX(), (int)_colorEllipse1.getY()+30);
   }
   else if (_type == 2){
    this.setLocation((int)_colorRectangle1.getX(), (int)_colorRectangle1.getY()+30);
   }
   else if (_type == 3){
    this.setLocation((int)_colorEllipse1.getX(), (int)_colorEllipse1.getY()+30);
   }
}
public int getXLocation(){
   if (_type == 1){
    return (int)_colorEllipse1.getX();
   }
   else if (_type == 2){
    return (int)_colorRectangle1.getX();
   }
   else if (_type == 3){
    return (int)_colorEllipse1.getX();
   }
   return 1;
}
public int getYLocation(){
   if (_type == 1){
    return (int)_colorEllipse1.getY()+30;
   }
   else if (_type == 2){
    return (int)_colorRectangle1.getY()+30;
   }
   else if (_type == 3){
    return (int)_colorEllipse1.getY()+30;
   }
   return 1;
}
public void fill(Graphics2D aBetterPen){
    if (_type == 1){
     _colorEllipse1.fill(aBetterPen);
     _colorEllipse2.fill(aBetterPen);
    }
    else if (_type == 2){
     _colorRectangle1.fill(aBetterPen);
     _colorRectangle2.fill(aBetterPen);
    }
    else if (_type == 3){
     _colorEllipse1.fill(aBetterPen);
     _colorRectangle1.fill(aBetterPen);
    }
}

public ColorShape getFirstShape(){
  if (_type == 1){
    return _colorEllipse1;
   }
  else if (_type == 2){
    return _colorRectangle1;
   }
  else if (_type == 3){
    return _colorEllipse1;
   }
   return null;
      }

public ColorShape getSecondShape(){
    if (_type == 1){
     return _colorEllipse2;
    }
    else if (_type == 2){
     return _colorRectangle2;
   }
    else if (_type == 3){
     return _colorRectangle1;   
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

my ColorEllipse is an Ellipse 2D Double and ColorRectangle is a Rectangle 2D double. They are both subclasses of ColorShape and inherit its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a floodfill algorithm to accomplish this.  Flood fill is used to fill in connected pixels of the same color in image editing programs like MSPaint or Photoshop.

Here's how it works (Edited):

1. Push starting point onto stack
2. While stack not empty, get next point.
3. If item at point is valid color, it will be set to null in your grid.
4. If item at point is valid color, push all cardinal neighbors onto stack.

I'll post some example code of the algorithm using your code above as much as possible.

```
public void removeLikeColorsFrom(ColorShape[][] _tiles, int x, int y){
    Color colorToReturn = _tiles[x][y].getColor();
    Stack<Point> stack = new Stack<Point>();
    stack.add(new Point(x,y));
    while(!stack.empty()){
        Point next = stack.pop();
        //check if this shape is the proper color
        if(_tiles[next.x][next.y].getColor().equals(colorToReturn)){
            _tiles[next.x][next.y] = null;
            x = next.x;
            y = next.y;
            //now push all neighbors onto stack for processing
            if(x-1>-1 && _tiles[x-1][y]!=null) 
                stack.push(new Point(x-1,y));
            if(x+1<tiles.length) 
                stack.push(new Point(x+1,y));
            if(y+1<tiles[0].length) 
                stack.push(new Point(x,y+1));
            if(y-1>-1) 
                stack.push(new Point(x,y-1));
        }
    }
}
```

This code works by recursively expanding from a start location.  ColorShapes which share a color with the desired color, and are connected on a path not requiring a diagonal will be set to null as you requested in comments.

Comment: hey thank you, it says that "type java.awt.List does not take parameters" though

Comment: Import java.util.List, not java.awt.List.  java.awt.list is a GUI component used for display.  java.util.List is a data structure.

Comment: Okay, so this method returns an List<ColorShape> right? because I don't see a return statement ;_;

Comment: how do you make the output set the _tiles[][] = null ?

Comment: Didn't realize that was your intention, edited the code to set valid points to null in array.  Algorithm no longer returns them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33008/discussion-between-user2533249-and-william-morrison)

Comment: "is if(x+1<tiles.length)"  suppose to be "if(x+1<_tiles.length)" and "if(y+1<tiles[0].length) " suppose to be "if(y+1<_tiles[0].length)"?

Comment: the line if(_tiles[next.x][next.y].getColor().equals(colorToRemove)){ gives a null pointer